# Using '-' character in sscanf with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I have the following code snippet:

```
char s[] = "2012-06-01-02";
int nYear;
int nMonth;
int nDay;
int nPass
sscanf(s, "%d-%d%-%d-%d", &nYear, &nMonth, &nDay, &nPass);
```

This code works as expected using Visual Studio, but I get the following compilation warning using gcc

```
warning: unknown conversion type character '-' in format
```

Then, if I run the code, I get the expected values for nYear, nMonth, but nDay and nPass are both 0.

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `%-` in there that I think you don't want.  Delete the `%`:

```
sscanf(s, "%d-%d%-%d-%d", &nYear, &nMonth, &nDay, &nPass);
                ^
                |--- delete this '%'
```

What you want to end up with looks like this:

```
sscanf(s, "%d-%d-%d-%d", &nYear, &nMonth, &nDay, &nPass);
```

As an aside, you might want to look into [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) if you're a beginner.  You'll get better error messages in cases like this, and it will help you learn faster.  Example:

```
example.c:10:22: warning: invalid conversion specifier '-'
      [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
    sscanf(s, "%d-%d%-%d", &nYear, &nMonth, &nDay, &nPass);
                    ~^
1 warning generated.
```